# step by step to run swashbuckle on ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I started running the project 'Swashbuckle.Dummy.SelfHost' by downloading Swashbuckle. Then I went to the browser and checked the URL that is declared in main function of program.cs class.when I give same URL in browser like 'http:/localhost:8090/swagger' I get below error. Can any one please guide me the step by step process to run the swash buckle solution and test it. If I want to host this application on IIS and run what are the steps I need to follow?

```
An error has occurred.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

System.IO.FileLoadException

at Swashbuckle.Application.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<>n__FabricatedMethod9(HttpRequestMessage , CancellationToken ) at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Did you try the [documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#getting-started)?  The re's a section on hosting IIS.  As far as the error you posted, it seems pretty self-explanatory to me - you're missing an assembly the application references.

Comment: I have followed the self host for this @Tim. As per you this error should have come at compile time right? but I am getting this error at run time

Comment: If you want to host it in IIS, then you need to follow the section title "IIS Hosted", not the self hosted section.  IIS hosting and self-hosting are two different things.  The error you are seeing is not a compile time error, it's a runtime error.  Make sure that the proper .NET framework is installed on the machine you're hosting the service on, and that the assembly is in the GAC.  If it's not, then copy the assembly to the bin folder of your IIS application that is hosting the service.

Comment: If the project didn't have the reference, then you'd see a compile time error telling you that it can't find the assembly that contains the class the program is trying to use.  Different causes, different types of errors.

Comment: I am trying to host this folder **Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core** in my IIS I am i going correct? @Tim

Comment: No that's not how you use Swashbuckle. You should just start with a new ASP.NET solution and then install Swashbuckle to your solution using NuGet, and then when you start your server you should be able to go to ~/swagger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is Swashbuckle is using System.Web.Http and System.Net.Http.Formatting assemblies in version 4. I am assuming that your application is using ASP MVC 5.x. In this case, you have to add binding redirects into your web.config.
Add following section into your web.config (swap '5.0.0.0' with the version of mentioned assemblies that your application is actually referencing):

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 1):

Salutation,

He has this to put in the runtime configuration section of your application :

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Best Regards.